# How to handle images in Vue Js form

Tags: javascript, rest, express, vue.js

I have a form in Vue for uploading a blog post it has areas for title, body, description, snippet, and photo. All are required.  I set an API up in Express to handle this, I tested it in Postman and it works but I can't figure out how to send the files to the database from the browser.
I keep getting a 500 error and I printed the data to the console and the photo field is null so I'm sure that's the issue but I just can't figure it out.

This is my form on the front end:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="nav">
      <adminnav/>
    </div>
    <div id="create">
      <h1>Create new post</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="post">
      <body>
        <form>
          <label for="title">Title: </label>
          <textarea v-model=formdata.title rows="5" cols="60" name="title"
            placeholder="Enter text">
          </textarea>
          <br/>
          <label for="body">Body: </label>
          <textarea v-model=formdata.body rows="5" cols="60" name="body"
            placeholder="Enter text">
          </textarea>
          <br/>
          <label for="description">Description: </label>
          <textarea v-model=formdata.description rows="5" cols="60" name="description"
            placeholder="Enter text">
          </textarea>
          <br/>
          <label for="snippet">Snippet: </label>
          <textarea v-model=formdata.snippet rows="5" cols="60" name="snippet"
            placeholder="Enter text">
          </textarea>
          <br/>
          <label for="file">Upload photo: </label>
          <input
            class="form-control-file"
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            v-bind="formdata.photo"
          />
          <br/>
          <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" @click.prevent="createPost()"/>
        </form>
      </body>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import adminnav from '../components/adminnav.vue';
import PostService from '../service/PostService';

export default {
  name: 'createStory',
  components: {
    adminnav,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      formdata: {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        description: '',
        snippet: '',
        photo: null,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createPost() {
      console.log(this.formdata);
      /* eslint prefer-destructuring: 0 */
      const formdata = this.formdata;
      PostService.createPost(formdata)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('success');
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the POST request.

```
router.post("/add-story", upload.single('photo'), async(req, res) => {
  try{
    let post = new Post();
    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.description = req.body.description;
    post.photo = req.file.location;
    post.body = req.body.body;
    post.snippet = req.body.snippet;

    await post.save();
    
    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: "Successfully saved."
    });
    
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: err.message
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's monitor the `change` event of the file `<input>`. This makes sure every time your users' upload behaviour triggers the method `updatePhoto` and store the file data in the `this.photo`.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file"
    @change="updatePhoto($event.target.name, $event.target.files)"
>
```

> Code to gather all data and send the request

```
// Other parts of your vue component
data () {
    return {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        description: '',
        snippet: '',
        photo: {} // To store file data
    };
},
methods: {
    updatePhoto (files) {
        if (!files.length) return;

        // Store the file data
        this.photo = {
            name: files[0].name,
            data: files[0]
        };
    },
    createPost() {
        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('title', this.title);
        formData.append('body', this.body);
        formData.append('description', this.description);
        formData.append('snippet', this.snippet);
        formData.append('photo', this.photo.data, this.photo.name);

        PostService.createPost(formdata)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('success');
        });
    }
}
// Other parts of your vue component
```

Obviously I skipped many things such as the whole vue component structure which I believe it's not related to this question and some necessary checks to make sure there is a file data available before launch the request and etc. It's an idea about how you can get the file data so hopefully this answer inspires you.

Comment: This worked.  I had to remove '$event.target.name' and everywhere else name showed up because it was giving me a weird error.  The name of the file isn't necessary anyway so I didn't look into it that deep.  Appreciate it!!